# Migrate module. Users from D6 to D7 with preserved UIDs

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to migrate a Drupal 6 site to a totally new implementation of Drupal 7.

I'm using the migrate module, and I am able to successfully migrate users and passwords, as well as their roles, but the users UIDs is not being maintained.

I believe that the issue is that UIDs must be explicitly set on the user object before saving it, and migrate is not doing that for me.

http://drupal.org/node/712966

Any tips on how I can do that? I need my UIDs on Drupal 7 to be exactly the same as Drupal 6!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For migrating to Drupal 7, it's much simpler:

```
// Pass the old uid through
$this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'uid');
// Tell user_save to create a new account with the given uid (otherwise it sees the
// uid and assumes you're updating an account).
$this->addFieldMapping('is_new')
     ->defaultvalue(1);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cribbing from [this](http://drupal.org/node/712966#comment-3208886)

> 1. Delete the original UID column in the destination users table
> 2. Create a new UID column (w/o primary and auto increment settings)
> 3. Map the source UID to the UID column
> 4. Perform the import
> 5. Add primary and auto increment settings to the UID column

If you need UIDs to be the same there is a chance that you are misusing them. There are a few cases where it matters (theme overrides perhaps) but in most cases it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I need UIDs to be the same so I can synchronize all modules correctly (Private messages, Nodes, Flags, etc...). Will matching UIDs be "discovered" somehow by Migrate?

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras to see what is supported.

Comment: Alright, but do you know if these migrate_extras supported features will recognize the old and new UIDs automatically, so I don't end with messed up entries?

Comment: And I REALLY need the UIDs to be the same, because I will integrate OpenAtrium with D7, and I already have hundreds of nodes on OA.

Comment: Then the above should work for you.

Comment: Note that in general Migrate keeps track of the ids it mapped, so if it sees a reference to a UID from the old system, it knows to look up the new UID on the other side. Same for any other id, when using sourceMigration.

Comment: Drupal constructs by default urls based on uid, so uid does matter. My old CMS also constructs user urls based on uid, so I needed this as well...